# Force scientific notation in tick labels of Plot in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to scientific-format tick labels on a my Plot which is somehow a frame. By searching Mathgroup archives, it looks like the usual way to mess with tick labels is to extract them using AbsoluteOptions, run a replacement rule with the custom format, and then explicitly feed them to the plotting function with the Ticks->{...} option. However, the following doesn't work for FrameTicks:

```
makePlotLegend[names_, markers_, origin_, markerSize_, fontSize_, 
   font_] := 
  Join @@ Table[{Text[Style[names[[i]], FontSize -> fontSize, font], 
      Offset[{1.5*markerSize, -(i - 0.5)*
         Max[markerSize, fontSize]*1.25}, Scaled[origin]], {-1, 0}], 
     Inset[Show[markers[[i]], ImageSize -> markerSize], 
      Offset[{0.5*markerSize, -(i - 0.5)*
         Max[markerSize, fontSize]*1.25}, Scaled[origin]], {0, 0}, 
      Background -> Directive[Opacity[0], White]]}, {i, 1, 
     Length[names]}];

LJ[r_] := 4 e ((phi/r)^12 - (phi/r)^6)

phi = 2.645;
e = 10.97 8.621738 10^-5;

l1 = Plot[LJ[r], {r, 2, 11}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
  PlotRange -> {{2, 6}, {0.001, -0.002}}, Frame -> True,
  LabelStyle -> {8}, 
  Epilog -> 
   makePlotLegend[{"He-He", 
     "H-H"}, (Graphics[{#, Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]}]) & /@ {Blue, 
      Red}, {0.80, 0.35}, 7.5, 7.3, "Times New Roman"]]
```

Comment: Take a look at [**this post**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9558)